# WSO2 physical server configuration issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We're currently working/testing/experimenting on WSO2. My question is that does WSO2 provides any service if the physical server itself (on which WSO2 is hosted) shuts down for any possible reason?

I know there may be several MANUAL alternatives for that but does WSO2 have a particular feature for **physical server migration**?

**Note:** Please let me know of what you think before down voting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by clustering which is supported by WSO2 products, please refer clustering documentation for more information [1]. Fail over and Switch over can be configured  automatically. Also you can achieve High Availability (HA) with multiple redundant nodes.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Overview

Comment: Thank you for your time.